# What is the reason behind this kind of error?

Tags: java

I'm very new to programming and I've been teaching myself for almost a month now, can someone please explain to methe reason behind error in my code? It errors in the ***"total(moneyConv(moneySum * moneyRate));" line,***
saying actual and formal argument differs in length. I've check all my parameters and it seemed fine to me. thanks a lot!

```
public class NewClass {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static float moneySum;
    public static float moneyRate;

    public static void findSum(float sum) {
        moneySum = sum;
    }

    public static void findRate(float rate) {
        moneyRate = rate;
    }

    public static float moneyConv(float sum, float rate) {
        return sum * rate;
    }

    public static void total(float total) {
        System.out.println(total + "Here is the total of your transaction.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Input amount of money : ");
        findSum(sc.nextFloat());
        System.out.print("Input exchange rate :  ");
        findRate(sc.nextFloat());

        total(moneyConv(moneySum * moneyRate));
    }
```

Comment: you probably meant `moneyConv(moneySum, moneyRate)`, previously you had `moneySum * moneyRate` (notice the comma in the first and the asterisk in the second snippet)

Answer (score 2):

the `moneyConv()` method parameters have 2 arguments: a `float` datatype `sum` and another `float` datatype `rate`. When you look at the method call:

```
total(moneyConv(moneySum * moneyRate));
```

you are actually trying to call the method `moneyConv(float sum, float rate)` but with one argument instead with a `float` datatype, as a result of the multiplication of `moneySum` and `moneyRate`. This is not valid since `moneyConv` accepts 2 arguments.

So, the fix would be `total(moneyConv(moneySum, moneyRate))`;

First the nested method `moneyConv(moneySum,moneyRate)` will be executed and after the method total will be executed with the result of the `moneyConv` method.

Answer (score 1):

Method parameters must be separated by commas:

```
total(moneyConv(moneySum, moneyRate));
```

`moneySum * moneyRate` is first evaluated and becomes a single value which is passed to `moneyConv` which actually requires two arguments.

It is equivalent to:

```
float temporary = moneySum * moneyRate;
total(moneyConv(temporary))
```

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Comment: I see now, I apologize for such a silly mistake and asking it here. I really had a hard time looking for solutions and none helped. Now I know why none of it worked. Thanks a lot guys!